# for loop inside twig.js, setting the loop counter

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I am using twig.js for templating. I have html div which displays 3 items from the items list.

```
<div class="item-container">
    {% set i = 0 %}
    {% for i in 0..items | length %}
    <ul>
        <li> {{ items[i].name }}     </li>
        <li> {{ items[i + 1].name }} </li>
        <li> {{ items[i + 2].name }} </li>
    <ul>
    {% set i = i + 3 %}
    {% endfor %} 
</div>
```

First iteration loop works fine, but `$i` will not be incremented using `{% set i = i + 3 %}`.
Can anyone tell me how to do this ?

Comment: I see there are valid solutions, but I'd still like to add the [`batch`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html) filter as an alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `range` function, it has `step` argument:

```
<div class="item-container">
{% for i in range(0, items|length-1, 3) %}
    <ul>
        <li>{{ items[i] }}</li>
        <li>{{ items[i+1]|default }}</li>
        <li>{{ items[i+2]|default }}</li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Instead of `default` filter you may use `{% if items[i+1] is defined %}`.

Comment: This works fine, if items length is more than step value. In case the item length is less than step value, twig will throw error.

Comment: @geekgugi Just wrap the loop with `if` clause checking `items|length < 3` or add this condition before defining the range.